# How to view Android app output through USB/ADB

Tags: android, adb

New to ADB and Android, so excuse my likely butchering of the terminology..

Google has an app available through their GitHub page (gps-measurement-tools) that allows you to view NMEA output in a terminal window, if you launch the app through Android Studio.

My question is now, how can I do this via the CMD and ADB, i.e. without relying on launching the app through the Android Studio? I know how to launch the app, but I don't see any output in the terminal window.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you see in Android Studio is just `logcat`. To reproduce without the Studio - start the app and then run `logcat` in the same `adb shell` session or `adb logcat` in a new window.

To see just `NMEA` events use the filter:

```
adb logcat GnssLoggerNmea:D
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to launch the application from Android Studio but on your Android Device using ADB.

- Install **ADB driver** for your device on your laptop/pc.
- Now    **enable Debugging mode** in your Android Device.(For this you
  have to **enable developer mode** on your android device).
- Connect android device with your laptop/pc and select **usb
  debugging mode** on android device.
- Now launch application from Android studio.